# Compiler optimized C function vs. manually written function with SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c, gcc, clang, simd, avx512

I'm exploring SIMD instructions and I have written a small function (see below) to find the first index of an integer `s` in a vector `v` of 16 integers using AVX512F intrinsics. The function looks pretty straightforward.

Is it possible to write the function in plain C such that GCC or Clang would be able to optimize it well? I've used Compiler Explorer (godbolt.org) to compare the assembly output of `find()` and `findc()`, and the C variant is always much more complicated. Am I on a fool's errand?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int 
find(int64_t s, int64_t *v)
{
        __m512i _s = _mm512_set1_epi64(s);
        __m512i _v0 = _mm512_load_epi64(&v[0]);
        __m512i _v1 = _mm512_load_epi64(&v[8]);
        __mmask8 m0 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi64_mask(_s, _v0);
        __mmask8 m1 = _mm512_cmpeq_epi64_mask(_s, _v1);
        uint32_t matches = (m1 << 8) | m0;
        return matches == 0 ? 32 : __builtin_ctz(matches);
}

int
findc(int64_t s, int64_t *v)
{       
        uint32_t __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) matches = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        {       
                matches |= (s == v[i]) << i;
        }
        return matches == 0 ? 32 : __builtin_ctz(matches);
}

int 
main()
{
        int64_t v[] = {40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 
            48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55};
        printf("find=%d\n", find(49, v));
        printf("findc=%d\n", findc(49, v));
}
```

Comment: The C code works at the bit level and the update of the variable`matches` creates a strong data dependency. Hence there is little that the compiler could vectorize.

Maybe you can split the code in a loop that performs just the comparisons, followed by a compression step, but I am not sure that this will suffice.

Comment: Optimization to the manually vectorized version: `uint32_t matches = (m1 << 8) | m0;` might be better written as `uint32_t  matches = _mm512_kunpackb(m1, m0)`.  It's either 2x kmov + GP-integer shift/OR, or it's kunpckbw + kmov and nothing else.  `kunpck` has 4 cycle latency, but this saves total uops and the integer shift/or would eat up 2 cycles of latency difference, and OoO exec can often hide latency.

Comment: You have AVX-512, so you should be able to depend on BMI1 for `_tzcnt_u32` to avoid special-casing 0 for `__builtin_ctz`.  (But shouldn't it be only 16 for the 0 case?  You only have 16 bits of mask data.  Unless 32 is an intentional sentinel value.)

Comment: I decided to use 32 as sentinel value, but I agree that 16 would work, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes AFAIK anything newer than 2015 should have BMI1 unless it's VIA

Comment: @Mgetz: Not Celeron/Pentium models, until I think Ice Lake.  Celeron/Pentium seem to use half-width SIMD, and if that's only 128-bit they disable decoding of VEX prefixes entirely, meaning they turn off BMI1/2 as well as AVX on Celeron/Pentium Skylake CPUs.  (This came to light when SKL had an erratum about incorrectly indicating support for BMI).  This is horrible, of course, putting more years before BMI1/2 can be a usable baseline.  (Which is when they're most useful, e.g. for variable-count shifts all through a codebase, not just in some hot functions.)

Comment: @Mgetz: Also I think low-power Silvermont-family CPUs like you find in some NAS boxes or other low-power servers, and some netbooks, also lacked VEX decoding until maybe Gracemont (Alder Lake E-cores) added in everything but AVX-512 (with 256-bit instructions split into 2 uops).  e.g. a Tremont i5-L16G7 (http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel/GenuineIntel00806A1_Lakefield_LC_InstLatX64.txt) doesn't have BMI1 or 2 or AVX.

Comment: @PeterCordes interesting I checked PG/PS 6xxx series before posting that... but it seems Intel is even more randomly inconsistent than even the pain of AVX. I'm not going to delete my comment because this exchange may be useful to future users trying to decide what to use.